# In iPad pro 11.2.5 App get crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

In my app, I have used one `textfield`. When tap on `textfield` the `device` `keyboard` will appear and than I type some text in that `textfield`. On that time the app get crashed in `iPad Pro 11.2.5` version. I don't know why the app getting crashed because the same code works perfect in `iPad Pro 10.3` version. Please review the my crash analytics report below

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x184410430 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x18514513c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1851446dc _CFXRegistrationPost + 420
3  CoreFoundation                 0x185144440 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1851c1e24 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1408
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18507ad60 _CFXNotificationPost + 380
6  Foundation                     0x185aa7348 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
7  UIFoundation                   0x18f8c4570 -[NSTextStorage processEditing] + 240
8  UIFoundation                   0x18f8c41d8 -[NSTextStorage endEditing] + 92
9  UIKit                          0x18e914368 -[UITextInputController _insertText:fromKeyboard:] + 488
10 UIKit                          0x18e9136d0 -[UITextInputController insertText:] + 400
11 UIKit                          0x18ead3518 -[UIFieldEditor insertFilteredText:] + 968
12 UIKit                          0x18f3eb3a0 -[UITextField insertFilteredText:] + 104
13 UIKit                          0x18e91343c -[UIKeyboardImpl insertText:] + 136
14 UIKit                          0x18ebd735c -[UIKeyboardImpl performKeyboardOutput:] + 756
15 UIKit                          0x18ebd665c __55-[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyboardInput:executionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 256
16 UIKit                          0x18f431fac -[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:] + 192
17 UIKit                          0x18e7975f0 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 384
18 Foundation                     0x185baf2e4 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 340
19 CoreFoundation                 0x18515b77c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
20 CoreFoundation                 0x18515b6fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
21 CoreFoundation                 0x18515af84 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
22 CoreFoundation                 0x185158b5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
23 CoreFoundation                 0x185078c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
24 GraphicsServices               0x186f24f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
25 UIKit                          0x18e7d15c4 UIApplicationMain + 236
26 Q App                          0x1050b756c main (main.m:16)
27 libdyld.dylib                  0x184b9856c start + 4
```

As my crash reports, I didn't use `NotificationCenter/observer` in that screen. But the crash reports are showing in the `NotificationCenter`. Please Any know the solution for this ?

Comment: Make sure once again, is there any `keyBoard` related `observer` added  ?

Comment: Is your `TextField` inside a `TableView` ?

Comment: NO. I added this text field inside the customAlert view

Comment: I'm having a similar problem that is also only happening in the latest ios versions. Did you find the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Note: The following is without knowing all required details because you did not provide any source code on how you implemented the feature nor does the crash report shown here contain any information about the exception code/signal being thrown.

The top frame shows the method `objc_msgSend` being invoked. This method is always used when the runtime tries to send a message (method) to an object. And crashes in this method usually mean the object doesn't exist any longer which means it was deallocated but your code still holds a reference.

So this looks like a memory management issue in your code. Without your actual implementation it is impossible to provide any meaningful help.

The best way to debug this is to run the app in debug mode and the device attached to Xcode and get more details. The Instrument tools can also help finding out where the problem is.

Comment: Hi Kerni,

Thanks for the replay. So if this is an memory management issue means  then thus crash not appeared in IPad pro 11.2.2 versions. It only appears in iPad Pro 11.2.5 onwards. So any idea why this appears only latest iOS versions?

Comment: It may have nothing to do with the OS version. You need to analyze your code.